# GitLab x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I am working with a Free GitLab server trying to use Git LFS (to lock/unlock files).

When trying to use several Git LFS commands, I get this error (*GitlabURL* is an abstract to hide my projects URL):

```
$ git lfs locks
Error while retrieving locks: Get "https://*GitlabURL*/info/lfs/locks?refspec=refs%2Fheads%2Fmain": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Now, I have tried GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 before commands and git config --global http.sslVerify false. While this does fix the issue and let me use git lfs commands, the issue is it will now not verify if the user has the ability to upload a locked file they have changed.
This means that if I have locked a file, another user can edit and push that file. I would like the other users to get their push rejected, but when turning SSL verify off, it does not do this check. It lets the users push changes with no problems.

Is there any way to fix this x509: certificate signed by unknown authority error so that I may lock files with Git LFS and where it prevents users from pushing changes to locked files until they are unlocked?

While this works, I would like a way to leave SSL verify on so that users are stopped when trying to push changes to locked files:

```
$ GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 git lfs locks
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
lockable.txt    Firstname Lastname    ID:7
```

Here's another example of the error:

```
$ git lfs lock lockable.txt
Locking lockable.txt failed: Post "https://hsvdagitb.sci.com/test_group1/test_project.git/info/lfs/locks": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: Where did you get the certificate on your GitLab server? Is it self-signed?

Comment: I believe it is self signed. I am not the one who created the server.

Comment: I am getting this with a certificate signed by Let's Encrypt—same as StackExchange, in fact.

I had this problem with curl on an outdated Ubuntu. It was solved by removing an outdated certificate (DST Root CA X3). Online comments lead me to believe this is/was an openssl bug, where it would give up rather than continue to search the signing roots for one that is still valid. (The offending cert expired in Sept 2021).